# Selecting the appropriate design pattern c#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am tasked with creating a payment module which consists of different types of payment methods.

There are different kind of objects that can go in each which can *slightly* change how some formulas are calculated. IE if a certain property is present, no tax is taken out. This is how I am currently going about it.

```
public abstract class Payment
{
    private readonly PersonToPay _personToPay;

    public Payment (PersonToPay personToPay)
    {
        _personToPay = personToPay;
    }

    public decimal PayFrom {get; set;}
    public decimal PayTo {get; set;}
    public decimal PayRate {get; set;}
    public decimal Gross {get; set;}
    public decimal Tax {get; set;}

    public void CalculateGross()
    {
        return PayRate * [days in period]
    }

    public void CalculateTax()
    {
        if (_personToPay.IsTypeOfX)
            Tax = 0;
        else
            Tax = PayRate * .1;
    }

    public virtual int GetDaysToPay()
    {
        int totalDays = 0;
        for (var x in _personToPay.ListOfItems)
        {
            if (x == someTypeOfValue)
                totalDays++;
        }

        return totalDays;
    }
}
```

I am trying to take all of the functionality in this class and pass it to other classes but since all of the functionality is tied to the 'PersonToThePay' object that is injected, how can I do as such in the derived classes? An example would be the following:

```
public PaymentMethodA : Payment
{
    private readonly PersonToPay _personToPay;
    public PaymentMethodA(PersonToPay personToPay)
    {
        _personToPay = personToPay; // this personToPay would set the parent classes PersonToPay above to this
    }

    public int PaymentMethodAProperty;
    public override int GetDaysToPay()
    {
        return PaymentMethodAProperty * 2;
        //do PaymentMethodA logic here
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could just make the PersonToPay a property but if you can't make a payment without a payee, doesn't it make more sense for it to be injected? I was also looking into the strategy pattern for this but to me the template seems to make more sense. Although the functionality is largely the same now, I am trying to make it as adaptable to change as possible hence the separate classes.

Any insight into what would be best to do here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Train i know about the strategy pattern but does it make sense to do so for just one method? It just seems odd.

Comment: If I understand, you should use interface for that classes. I would create global payment class which accepts all payment methods which implement IPaymentMethod interface.

Comment: Why would a payment method need to know who is being paid?

Comment: yes good point @TheBatman, the payment class should accept who is paid and payment method and do the payment.

Comment: @TheBatman the functionality changes depending on who the recipient is (IE where they live, what type of tier they are in, etc.)

Comment: Yes it's a small sample but the code is still pretty straight forward and quite extensible in case payment methods change, which in real life they do. Just remember the most important thing, If it works good enough to make the company money don't complicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two questions here: The first is what's a good pattern. It's subjective but I'd use a strategy pattern as well. Something to allow the implementation to be something that doesn't care what the payment is:

```
IPayment payment = new Payment() { PaymentAmount = 100 };
IPayment nonProfitPayment = new NonProfitPayment() { PaymentAmount = 100 };
Console.WriteLine($"Total for 100 payment: ${payment.TotalPayment()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Total for 100 payment: ${nonProfitPayment.TotalPayment()}");
```

Which of course gives: $106.00 and $100.

The class definitions being:

```
public interface IPayment
{
    decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
    decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }

    decimal TotalPayment();
}

public class Payment : IPayment
{
    public Payment()
    {
        TaxRate = 0.06M;
    }
    public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPayment()
    {
        return PaymentAmount + (PaymentAmount * TaxRate);
    }
}

public class NonProfitPayment : Payment
{
    public NonProfitPayment()
    {
        TaxRate = 0;
    }
}
```

And then for the second question: A Payee and a Payor.

IMO these should be two additional classes, passed to a PostPayment class / Method. A Quick Pseudo class:

```
public class PostPayment: IPostPayment
{
    public PaymentResponse PostPayment(IPayee payee, IPayor payor, IPayment payment)
    {
        var totalPayment = payment.TotalPayment();
        var payorStatus = payor.Charge(totalPayment);
        if (payorStatus == ChargeStatus.InsuffucientFunds)
        {
           return PaymentResponse.InsuffificientCredit;
        }
        return payee.Credit(totalAmount).PaymentStatus;
    }
}
```

This ultimately ensures that any weird things for a Type of a thing, is handled by the correct thing. For additional thoughts:

```
public class ReallyWeirdPayeeCase : IPayee
{
    public PaymentStatus Credit(decimal paymentAmount)
    {
         var approval = new ApprovalRequired()
         {
             ApprovalRequired = true,
             Amount = paymentAmount,
             DaysHoldRequired = 30
         };
         dbContext.CorporateApproval.Add(approvalRequired);
         return PaymentStatus.ThirtyDayApprovalQueued;
    }
}
```

**Shooting from the hip** but, I think it shows one good approach to refactoring the existing code for Single Responsibility and meeting your needs.

Comment: @Train, thanks! It takes a little longer, and often gets little to no recognition but: It's a fun thing ;)

Comment: @AustinTFrench fwiw, I really appreciate the help and I loved the response. I hope that one day I will be able to assist others just as well as you have done for me. Thank you again for your help!